# I am trying to convert some columns in a DataFrame from float to integers

Tags: pandas, type-conversion

I am using .astype but all I cant find in documentation is converting the whole df not just a few columns.  Any advise?

Date: 2019-05-13             volume: 3.464018e+08     volatility: 3.507323e+09

When I try to do np computations on these numbers I get an error saying number is finite not infinite.  So I am thinking may be it doesn't recognize e+0 in the end which would change if converted to ints.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the example dataframe?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers need good questions. Have a look at [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can edit your questions to make it easier to get help.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is `astype` method.

As the parameter, you can pass a dictionary "columnName: type"
to specify the target type for each column:

```
df.astype({'volume': np.int64, 'volatility': np.int64})
```

As the test data I used:

```
data = [['2019-05-13', 3.464018e+08, 3.507323e+09],
        ['2019-05-14', 3.2024e+08,   3.730523e+09],
        ['2019-05-15', 3.36706e+08,  3.3246783e+09]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date','volume', 'volatility'])
```

The result of conversion was:

```
         Date     volume  volatility
0  2019-05-13  346401800  3507323000
1  2019-05-14  320240000  3730523000
2  2019-05-15  336706000  3324678300
```

Note that just `int` is (or at least may be) not enough.
The reason it that in this case the number size is **platform dependent**.
On my computer it was `int32`, so e.g. values in *volatility* column were
converted to *-2147483648* (due to overflow).

Of course, to use explicitely *Numpy* data types like I did,
you should *import numpy as np*.

Other way is to define target types as *string*, in this case just `'int64'`.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting errors with the dict method because I used int64 not np.int64.

Comment: hi I tried the np.int64 and I am still getting this error:KeyError: 'Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype mappings argument.'

Comment: update: when ran all cells it worked.  Thanks so much!